# Медсестра и медбрат

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правда ли, что не существует понятия "медбрат", и даже мужчин этой профессии правильно называть "медсестра"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неправда. :) «Русский орфографический словарь» РАН не только фиксирует слово *медбрат,* но и не даёт при нём никаких ограничительных помет.

Answer (score 0):

Орфографический словарь (Лопатина, видимо) в данном случае не показатель. Там и "балерун" приводится без помет. Надо толковый смотреть.

"Медбрат" действительно давно проникло в живую речь, но правильное название мужчин этой профессии - "медицинский работник среднего звена".

==========

не получается почему-то комментировать. отвечаю здесь.
Behemothus вполне может ошибаться, только давно ли "партия и правительство" стали командовать русским языком?
Что такое ОКПРДСТР мне известно, но Вы лучше всё-таки загляните в толковый словарь, для филолога (даже дилетанствующего подобно мне) это более всё-таки гораздо более надежный источник.

Comment: Медбрат.

Медицинский брат; санитар.

Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000.

МЕДБРАТ. Сокращение: медицинский брат - лицо среднего медицинского персонала в лечебных учреждениях.

Толковый словарь Ожегова. С.И. Ожегов, Н.Ю. Шведова. 1949-1992.

Comment: Забано. Ну ладно, сдаюсь перед авторитетом. Я-то смотрел только то, что под рукой в сети. Там не было. А уж про древнего Ожегов даже не мыслил.
Хотя внутренне я всё равно против. "Медсестра" мотивировано исходным "сестра милосердия" (*чья* сестра, заметьте, не *какая*), а брат-то каким боком тут?
--
Комментировать научился наконец, но из другого браузера, извините.

Answer (score 0):

**behemothus** ошибается.

В ОБЩЕРОССИЙСКОМ КЛАССИФИКАТОРЕ ПРОФЕССИЙ РАБОЧИХ, ДОЛЖНОСТЕЙ СЛУЖАЩИХ И ТАРИФНЫХ РАЗРЯДОВ есть *медицинский брат*. Хотя в Приказе №526 (об утверждении профессиональных и квалификационных групп должностей медицинских и фармацевтических работников) от 6 августа 2007 года такой должности нет, в Постановлении Правительства от 29 октября 2002 года №781 написано, что должность медсестры, занимаемой мужчиной, необходимо именовать *медбратом*. В Постановлении Минздрава от 23 июля 2010 года № 541 в п.7 1-го раздела написано то же самое: *медбрат*.

Comment: Когда нам выдавали корочки, то всем - и девушкам, и парням писали "младшая медсестра", сказав, что понятия "медбрат" нет.

Answer (score 0):

Медбрат — это обиходное выражение, поскольку мужчину называть сестрой как бы не очень удобно. Но в действительности Медицинская сестра происходит от специализации Сестринское дело. В России ни когда не было и нет Братского дела поэтому медбрат это вымысел для устного наименования специалиста мужского рода со средним профессиональным медицинским образованием по специализации Сестринское дело. В дипломе, в трудовой, в штатном расписании и остальных письменных документах пишется Медицинская сестра.

Comment: В целом -  да.
Не уверен насчет диплома... В смысле - писать-то могут, насколько это правильно.
Могу только повторить, что по этому поводу когда-то видел разъяснение, что мужчин величают просто медработниками соеднего звена.
И вот насчет "сестринского дела". С точки зрения этимологии это все-таки вторично. Первично - сестра милосердия. Не какая, заметьте, а *чья*.

Comment: Недавно задумавшись над этим вопросом, спросила подругу, которая учится в медколледже. Она говорит, мужчинам в дипломе действительно пишут "Медицинский брат".